# How to use SEL_MenuHandler/menu_handler in as function argument Cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x

I used cocos2dx to build a game.

Back in V 2.x I used this :

```
void Popup::addButtonWithText(const char* text, 
                              CCObject* target, 
                              SEL_MenuHandler selector)
```

and while using the popup object I utilised this as :

```
popup->addButtonWithText("TEXT", this, menu_selector(Class::FunctionName));
```

Now in V 3.1.1 I am using this :

```
void Popup::addButtonWithText(const char* text, 
                              Object* target, 
                              SEL_MenuHandler selector)
```

and while using the popup object I utilised this as :

```
popup->addButtonWithText("TEXT", this, menu_selector(Class::FunctionName));
```

But in V 3.1.1 I am getting error :

```
Static_cast from void to cocos2d::SEL_MenuHandler is not allowed
```

I am doing the same thing, so why am I getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this recent discussion on the topic: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-use-sel-menuhandler-menu-handler-in-as-function-argument/14823